# Is it legal for a vendor to reuse credit details from a previous transaction

Tags: credit-card, online-payment

I purchased an item online. I got a phone call from them touting some other service. All I said was OK- I didn't understand the details and they charged again a big amount using the originally submitted credit cards detail. I am currently disputing the second transaction. 
Is it even legal? If it was then it would be worthless making an purchase.

Their physical location is Illinois, US.  Mine is Saitama, Japan.

Comment: Please state your country/State. In some places there are laws protecting consumers from predatory sales, in others there are laws protecting businesses from "regretful" consumers.

Answer (score 2):

It is very much legal and in fact depending on the fine print of the purchase you make, you have now established a business relationship among which gives the business the right to hold on to your information (unless privacy policy states otherwise) and reuse it under certain circumstances (such as auto shipments) and when they called and asked you if you wanted it and you said OK, you acknowledged authorization. All legal even if pushy and less than pretty.

Comment: Yeah. Saying 'ok' meant you entered into a verbal contract with them and you can be ABSOLUTELY SURE they recorded the call and so can produce proof of contract.

Comment: It was only vague statements- he at no point actually said he was selling anything or setting an agreement/contract.

Comment: The business himself said he was directing accounts to charge my credit card- the only time he talked about money. Sorry my mistake- I will never American based company every again- they are just disreputable businesses.

Comment: No fine print. No purchase statement at all.